# How to create this type of inner shadow in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

Please zoom in on the thumbnail.

That shadow or depth are from all 4 corners.

Forgive me I am a beginner with Photoshop and don't even know the name for that effect.

Any help would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not shadow, nor depth. This effect is called vignette and can be achieved easily, if you open image, go to `Filter > Lens Correction` or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, click to `custom` tab and alter sliders in `Vignette` field

[image]

Comment: I have just started web designing in photoshop would you or anyone know anyplace for tutorials and forums. I know we cant have debates here..Can someone point me in right direction...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Choose a rounded rectangle marquee tool. keep feather to 60 to 80 px whichever suits your need ..... Draw the rectangle on the image leaving distance of 5-10 px approx more or less. Now press Ctrl + shift + i and fill the rectangle color with black or dark grey

Or

First draw a dark grey or black rectangle on the image of same size . then Using the same feather options on rounded rectangle draw a rectangle leaving 5-10 px distance from all the sides. press delete and bingo.. U can adjust its opacity or try different blending options